# Rails Controller testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd

I am doing the thoughtbot intro to testing program. Im not sure how to test for what they want.

Below is my test.

```
require "rails_helper"

describe PeopleController do
  describe "#create" do
    context "when person is valid" do
      it "redirects to #show" do

        post :create, FactoryGirl.build_stubbed(:person)

        expect(response).to redirect_to(show_people_path)
      end
    end

    context "when person is invalid" do
      it "redirects to #new" do
        pending "create this test"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I am of course using factory girl. I have tried several methods. I really don't know hoe to test this controller.

Any insights would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an 'invalid' person using the FactoryGirl, and send it as a parameter to the `post :create`.

To create an invalid person record, why don't you use [nested factories](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#inheritance) in FactoryGirl? Depending on the validation in your model, you can simply do something like:

**spec/factories/person.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :person do
    ...
    factory :invalid_person do
      ...
      email nil
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

**in your test**

```
context "when person is invalid" do
  it "redirects to #new" do
    post :create, FactoryGirl.build_stubbed(:invalid_person)
    expect(response).to redirect_to action: :new
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. This makes more sense now. However my terminal is throwing an uninitialized constant FactoryGirl error... hrm..